# Get pixel brightness with p5.js

Tags: javascript, image, pixel, p5.js

I'm trying to get the pixel data from an image to calculate the image's average brightness. I have no problem accessing the data with `img.loadPixels();` but for some reason some elements of the pixel array are `undefined`, which breaks my computation.

Here is the code for `sketch.js`:

```
var img;
var brightness;
var inc;
var gotBright = false;

function preload(){
   img = loadImage('assets/2.png');
}

function setup(){
   createCanvas(500, 500);
   background(0);

}

function draw(){

   img.resize(10, 10);
   image(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height);

   brightness = 0;
   inc = 0;

   if (gotBright == false) {

      img.loadPixels();
      loadPixels();
      for (var i = 0; i < img.width; i++) {
         for (var j = 0; j < img.height; j++) {
            var index = (i * j * img.width) * 4;
            var r = img.pixels[index + 0];
            var g = img.pixels[index + 1];
            var b = img.pixels[index + 2];

            brightness += (r + g + b) / 3;
            inc ++;
            console.log(inc, r , g, b);
         }
      }
      gotBright = true;
      brightness = brightness/inc;
   }
}
```

`brightness` should be equal to some number between 0 and 255, but now it's `NaN`...

If you have recommendations on other methods to calculate average brightness of an image, I am happy to hear them :)
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your index calculation is wrong. Shouldn't it be:

`var index = (i + j * img.width) * 4;`

Answer (score 0):

[Bauer's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47888970/873165) is on the right track. You need to make sure your pixel index is correct. The best way to do that is to get out a piece of graph paper and draw out some examples.

Or you could just use the `get()` function that takes an `x` and a `y` parameter. From [the reference](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5.Image/get):

```
var myImage;
var c;

function preload() {
  myImage = loadImage("assets/rockies.jpg");
}

function setup() {
  background(myImage);
  noStroke();
  c = myImage.get(60, 90);
  fill(c);
  rect(25, 25, 50, 50);
}
```